# Paste from clipboard using "+p or "*p on OSX?

Tags: vim, vi

I can not use both <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> or <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> to paste from clipboard to Vim

Vim always make error sound when I press <kbd>*</kbd> or <kbd>+</kbd>

Thank you

Comment: Which Vim (and version) do you use, and does it come with clipboard support (i.e. `:version` lists `+clipboard`)?!

Comment: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 which shipped with my macbook air mid 2013

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default Vim is built *without* clipboard support.

If that's what you are using, consider installing [MacVim](https://code.google.com/p/macvim/) and the bundled `mvim` script: you can then use

```
$ mvim file
```

to edit `file` in the GUI or

```
$ mvim -v file
```

to edit `file` in CLI Vim and enjoy (among other things) clipboard support.

Easy.